# How to add context menu to the "outline" view in VsCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I've been trying to add a context menu to the "outline" view in VsCode.

In the Extension API documentation I did not see any reference to the Outline View. 
I also tried using the below configuration to get the context menu, but it doesn't seem to work

```
"view/item/context": [
        {
            "command": "my-extension.myCommand",
            "when": "view == outline"
        }
    ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this is currently possible, the `"view/item/context"` contribution point seems to be limited to context menus of custom views. Built-in views [have their own contribution points](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/contribution-points#contributes.menus), such as `"explorer/context"` or `"scm/resource/context"`.

There's an open feature request to allow this:

- [Allow extensions to contribute to Outline context menu / menu bar (#67935)](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/67935)